# Binded DataGridView to List<T> not showing data

Tags: c#, winforms, list, generics, datasource

This is the code I have (it a very simple example):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Person> listPersons;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listPersons = new List<Person>();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = listPersons;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = textBox1.Text;
            listPersons.Add(p);
        }
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When you press the button, data IS added to the list, but it doesn't show up in the `DataGridView`. What am I missing?

I have tried setting `AutoGenerateColumns` and `VirtualMode` to `true`, but that didn't resolve the issue either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But if I use only `BindingList<T>` instead of `List<T>` it does work.

Example code:

```
    BindingList<Person> bl;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bl = new BindingList<Person>();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bl;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = textBox1.Text;
            bl.Add(p);
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
    }
```

*But I would still like to figure out how to show data in `DataGridView` after bindng it with List.*

Answer (score 3):

It's been awhile, and I've switched jobs since working on WinForms code that tried to bind List<T>s to DataGridViews. If I recall correctly, whatever you bind needs to implement IBindingList, which List<T> doesn't. I may be wrong on that.

In any case, what I used was [BindingListView](http://blw.sourceforge.net/), which was incredibly fast and easy. You just do:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomers();
BindingListView<Customer> view = new BindingListView<Customer>(customers);
dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
```

And you're done. I haven't looked at the source in a few years, but I believe it wraps the List<T> with a class that implements IBindingList.

Comment: +1 The documentation for DataGridView says that a DataSource implementing IList will work, but that IBindingSource is preferred since it takes care of a lot of binding issues automatically, presumably ones like this.

Comment: @jam40jeff: Yeah, I had to look it up. IBindingList appears to be a requirement if you want to sort the list in any way.

Comment: Sorry, no BindingListView class in VS 2008 and older.Will try to do it the same with BindingList class - let you know

Comment: No, using BindingList<T> does NOT work. It still dont not update the dataGridView (and I repeat, I dont have any BndingListView class).

Comment: @MitjaBonca: BindingListView isn't built in. It's a third-party library (check the link).

Answer (score 1):

use array for binding datagridview ie

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Person[] listPersons = new Person[0];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = listPersons;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = textBox1.Text;
            Array.Resize<Person>(ref listPersons, listPersons.Length+1);
            listPersons[listPersons.Length-1]=p;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = listPersons;
        }

    }


}
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Centralize your `FillGrid` functionality and call it when you want to update the grid

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
     listPersons = new List<Person>();

    FillGrid();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = textBox1.Text;
        listPersons.Add(p);

        FillGrid();
    }
}

private void FillGrid()
{
   dataGridView1.DataSource = listPersons;
}
```

Comment: So every time I will Set DataSource? No, and this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly bind list to datagridview.
Instead use BindingList.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<Person> lstBinding;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lstBinding = new BindingList<Person>();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lstBinding;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = textBox1.Text;
            lstBinding.Add(p);
            FillGrid();
        }
    }
    private void FillGrid()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = lstBinding;
    }
}

class Person
{
    private string name;
    public string Name 
    { 
        get {return name;}
        set { name = value; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling `dataGridView1.Refresh();` after adding to the list.