# How to display List<string> property in DataGridView in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, db4o

so I am having a problem and I can't find the right answer.
So I have the Department class:

```
 public class Department
{
    // attributes
    public int DNumber { get; set; }
    public string DName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Locations { get; set; }
    // relationships
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    // one-to-many relationship (manager) attribute
    public string MgrStartDate { get; set; }

}
```

this is how I add value:

```
public static void CreateDepartment(IObjectContainer db, string fileName)
    {
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader fin = new StreamReader(fs);
            int nDpms = int.Parse(fin.ReadLine());
            for (int i = 0; i < nDpms; i++)
            {
                string line = fin.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    string[] fields = line.Split(':');
                    int dnumber = int.Parse(fields[0]);
                    string dname = fields[1];
                    string[] locationFields = fields[2].Split(',');
                    List<string> locations = new List<string>(locationFields);

                    Department d = new Department
                    {
                        DNumber = dnumber,
                        DName = dname,
                        Locations = locations
                    };
                    db.Store(d);
                }
            }
            fin.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

and I want to display List<'string> Locations (don't mind the 'string). So I use this code:

```
private void Form_Department_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database.DbFileName = "Database.yap";
        db = Database.Db;

        loadDepartment();
    }

    private void loadDepartment()
    {
        var department = new Department();
        result = db.QueryByExample(department);
        dataGridView_Department.DataSource = result;
    }
```

But the DataGridView only show things that are not List<'T>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcP5a.png)

As you can see, it doesn't have Locations, or Employees,...

That is my question.
Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binded DataGridView to List<T> not showing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024893/binded-datagridview-to-listt-not-showing-data)

Comment: When you set the grids `DataSource`, then the grid will display all the publicly exposed properties that are NOT Collections or a Class. It will only display columns for “single” value properties. In the `Department` class `Locations`, `Employees` and `Projects` are all “collections”… and the grid is not smart enough to know how to put “multiple” items into a single cell. You can either “flatten” the collection or possibly use multiple grids in a master-detail scenario.

Comment: so what you mean is that, I should change it from list to just not list right?

Comment: Not necessarily… In the `Department` class, since `Locations` is a `List<string>` … you could do something like make a `LocationStrings` property and return all the locations in the list as a “single” `string.` The same would apply to the other collections. It is unknown what properties the `Employee` and `Project` classes have, but if they have a `ToString()` method then technically you could also “flatten” those values. The idea is that the grid wants a “single” value to put in a cell.

Comment: A master-detail scenario would use multiple grids such that the first (master) grid would contain the Department properties as you have shown. Then there could be another (detail) grid that shows all the Locations for the “selected” department in the first (master) grid. And possibly a third (detail) grid to show the employees and a fourth to show the projects.

Comment: wow, now that is a good way to solve it. Thank you so much.

Comment: To help, if you are going to use a master-detail scenario… then set ALL the grids to the same `DataSource`… then for each detail grid, set it’s `DataMember` property to point to the property you want to display in the grid. Example, the `Locations` grids `DataMember` would be “Locations”, "Employees" grid would have a `DataMember` of “Employees” and obviously the projects grid would have the `DataMember` set to “Projects.” This way… each detail grid will then “update” automatically whenever a different `Department` is selected in the master grid.

Comment: should I create a second DataGridView to show list<'T>?

Comment: because my teacher give us these classes and told us to use them for displaying the db4o database.